# Add salt or not to soaking Wheat? (for wheat porridge)

Tags: baking, salt, grains, soaking, breakfast

I just discovered using a rice cooker with a delay function!

So I have started adding Cracked Wheat (not the parboiled Bulghur, but simply Cracked Wheat Berries) and water into the rice cooker where it sits for 10 hours until it turns on and has it ready for my breakfast.

But I'm wondering if I should be adding salt into the soaking water, or will this make it not cook properly?

(I believe I have seen this be said about it making beans not cook properly, and possibly for pearl barley as well?)

(Many recipes also say, for some reason, about waiting until the water is already boiling before salting. But this salt would be sitting in the cold water before it is even bought to the boil.)

Should I add salt to the soaking water? (also, would this be different for certain grains? Such as oats, millet, or the barley?)

Thanks!

Comment: one reason not to put put salt in cold water is because it doesn't dissolve right away, and therefore can sit on the bottom of the pot and cause it to corrode.

Answer (score 1):

Adding salt will not prevent the porridge from cooking properly. The same is true of cooking beans.

Adding salt at the beginning of the cooking process can under some circumstances lead to corrosion of a steel cooking vessel. This does not apply to the PTFE-coated aluminum of your average rice cooker.